# Splitting one Column into two based upon when a specific character shows up

Tags: r

I have a dataset that includes a column with the following information:

Kay Ivey (R)

Mike  Dunleavy (R)

Doug Ducey (R)...

Basically, the name of a Governor with the political party in parentheses next to it. How can I split the columnn into two with the name in one column and the Political Party designation in another. I have tried using the separate() function, but cannot figure out how to accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `extract` to capture substring as a group (`(...)`) to create two columns i.e. capture all characters until the `(`, then capture the letter as second group

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, name, into = c("name", "designation"), "(.*)\\(([^)]+)\\)")
#            name designation
#1      Kay Ivey            R
#2 Mike Dunleavy            R
#3    Doug Ducey            R
```

Or with `separate` by specifying the `sep` as zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) followed by the bracket (`\\(` - escaped as it is a metacharacter) or the `\\)` and specify to "drop" the `extra` column (otherwise there would be a friendly warning)

```
df1 %>% 
  separate(name, into = c('name', 'designation'),
          sep="\\s*\\(|\\)$", extra = "drop")
 #          name designation
 #1      Kay Ivey           R
 #2 Mike Dunleavy           R
 #3    Doug Ducey           R
```

---

Or in `base R`  with `read.csv` after creating a delimiter while replacing the `()` using `gsub`

```
read.csv(text = gsub("\\s\\(([^)]+)\\)", ",\\1", df1$name), 
     header = FALSE, col.names = c('name', 'designation'))
#          name designation
#1      Kay Ivey           R
#2 Mike Dunleavy           R
#3    Doug Ducey           R
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("Kay Ivey (R)", "Mike Dunleavy (R)", 
"Doug Ducey (R)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```

Comment: When I use that code it gives me the following error: Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has the wrong type `tbl_df<
  State   : character
  Governor: character
  Party   : character
>`.
ℹ It must be numeric or character.

Comment: @ls22 I added the data you used.  Can you test on that data

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_match` from `stringr` :

```
stringr::str_match(df$name, '(.*?)\\s*\\((.*)\\)')

#     [,1]                [,2]            [,3]
#[1,] "Kay Ivey (R)"      "Kay Ivey"      "R" 
#[2,] "Mike Dunleavy (R)" "Mike Dunleavy" "R" 
#[3,] "Doug Ducey (R)"    "Doug Ducey"    "R"
```

We capture the name of the governor in the first capture group and name of the political party which is in parenthesis in another capture group.

---

Using base R, extracting separately with similar regex :

```
transform(df, governor = sub('(.*?)\\s*\\(.*', '\\1', name),
              party = sub('.*\\((.*)\\)', '\\1', name))

#              name      governor party
#1      Kay Ivey (R)      Kay Ivey     R
#2 Mike Dunleavy (R) Mike Dunleavy     R
#3    Doug Ducey (R)    Doug Ducey     R
```